# EditText is not hide when scroll up item Recycle android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm refer this link to scroll up Recycle:

```
https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part2)/
```

This is my result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhHcL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mK65.png)

My Activity:

```
public class PartOneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private EditText editTextSearcch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeRed);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initEditTextSearch();
    initRecyclerView();
}

private void initEditTextSearch() {
    editTextSearcch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
}

private void initRecyclerView() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(createItemList());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            hideViews();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            showViews();
        }
    });
}

private void hideViews() {
    editTextSearcch.animate().translationY(-editTextSearcch.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
}

private void showViews() {
    editTextSearcch.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
}

private List<String> createItemList() {
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        itemList.add("Item "+i);
    }
    return itemList;
  }
 }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.PartOneActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextSearch" />


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:hint="Input text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I scroll down, EditText is show and fine. But when scroll up, EditText is not hide and it's still appear on ToolBar

I think maybe I set the value for position show and hide are incorrect, But How to set value to hide EditText. You can see photos at my attachment files

Comment: Use a FrameLayout

Comment: Hi, I have used FrameLayout but same the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the order of elements in your layout. Put EditText higher than the view it is supposed to hind behind (Toolbar) in RelativeLayout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.PartOneActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextSearch" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:hint="Input text" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set Visibility GONE for edit text,may be it works

Comment: Please make edit text a part of recycler view. Right now you are having it outside the recycler view

Comment: What confusion?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your problem correctly - you just need to use [AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) within [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) and apply a special behaviour to your RecyclerView or ViewGroup that contains it. The tutorial you mentioned looks kind a hack, can't you the default approach? That guy which tutorial you are using mentioned that it is outdated, use his newest [sample](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/)!

 I prefer such approach :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```